# Android. How to speed up XmlPullParser?

Tags: android, performance, android-xml, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I have XML database which weights around 72MB. It has ~170k entries [like this](http://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/jmdict_sample.html).
I am parsing this database using XmlPullParser. Parsing process is very long(more than 5 minutes). I think this is not good for dictionary application. I am parsing in this way:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/JMdict/JMdict.xml");
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
            xpp.setInput(stream, null);

            int index = 0;
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && index < 10) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals(ENTRY_GLOSS)) {
                        xpp.next();
                        if (xpp.getText().contains(searchWord)) {
                            index++;
                            Log.d(LOGTAG, xpp.getText());
                        }
                    }
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
```

What I am doing wrong? What to change in order to speed up parsing process to less than a second?

Comment: why don't you convert it to another format like sqlitedb?

Comment: The format of your dataset is far from optimal for your use case scenario (mobile device, searching/look ups). In stead, pre-process the data into a format more suitable for this. As mentioned above, a SQLite database is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **[Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)** Framework to parse xml , it's Faster than `XmlPullParser`

Answer (score 0):

I think XmlPullParser is highly optimised and fast.  However, there're some tricks when using it. For example, try to skip those tags that you don't need them